# Github Search API filename only returns 1 result

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to search for all projects (or at least several thousand) from the github search API. I've gotten everything else to work, except the filters on filename.

For example, sending the following request to the search API only returns 1 result:

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=django+in:requirements.txt+filename:requirements.txt+language:python+org:openmicroscopy
```

Likewise, sending the following

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=filename:Makefile&per_page=100
```

only returns 1 result as well. I'm willing to bet that there is more than 1 repo on github with a Makefile or a dependency on Django. I must be doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post](https://developer.github.com/changes/2013-10-18-new-code-search-requirements/) on Github's developer site to support the expected volume of requests, they have added restrictions to code queries which requires us to specify set of users, organizations, or repositories with the query. Read about considerations for code search at this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#considerations-for-code-search)

Now, about your search API requests, in the first one the **in** qualifier is provided with file name ***requirements.txt*** which is wrong.
The documentation states that **in** should be provided with ***file*** to restrict the search to the file contents, ***path*** to restrict the search to the file path or both.
Like this, **in:file**, **in:path**,  **in:file,path**

So, if you want to search in file contents the correct API call should be

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=django+in:file+filename:requirements.txt+org:openmicroscopy
```

I removed the **language** qualifier since you are searching in a **.txt** file and doing this improved the result.

Checkout this URL, it will produce same results on the website,

```
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=org%3Aopenmicroscopy+django+in%3Afile+filename%3Arequirements.txt&type=Code
```

Your second query is a repository search, it cannot not take a filename as qualifier you should see this [link](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#parameters) for available qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should've chose a better example for the first one, I actually pulled that one off of another accepted answer to a question. The second search was what I was doing, and it seems you are right. It seems like if the github API sent back an error with that request instead of processing it, I would've saved an hour of googling...

Comment: Glad it helped :D